# jQM Fail to get height and width on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

The jQM width() and height() return 0 with DIV ID.

My CSS making the DIV BG red just to make sure the div have full 100% width and height. It does show red in full screen.

I try to get height and width on "pagebeforeshow" page event, but return 0.

If I navigate to another page and return to "userMainPage", the height and width will show correct number. Just initial load it will return 0.

Please point out my error on why initial load give me 0 for width and height. Thank you.

**My HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="userMainPage">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="false" data-position="fixed" data-id="main-header" data-theme="a">
        <a href="#leftPanel" class="ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Left Panel</a>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <a href="#rightPanel" class="ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Right Panel</a>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#userMainPage" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist" data-transition="none">Promotions</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#restaurantList" data-transition="none">Restaurants</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='userMPContent' data-role="content" class="top77">
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div id="swiper1">
                        Slide 1 Here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div id="swiper2">
                        Slide 2 Here
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div id="swiper3">
                        Slide 3 Here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My JS:**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#userMainPage', function () {
    var height = $('#userMPContent').height();
    var width = $('#userMPContent').width();
    $('.swiper-container').css('width', width);
    $('.swiper-container').css('height', height);
    $('.swiper-slide').css('width', width);
    $('.swiper-slide').css('height', height);
    console.log('Height: ' + height);
    console.log('Width: ' + width);
    var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
        //Your options here:
        mode: 'horizontal',
        autoResize: true,
        loop: false
        //etc..
    }); 
});
```

**and my CSS:**

```
#userMPContent {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The only way to get dimensions or offset of an element is on `pagecontainershow` when pages and all elements are visible.

Comment: Omar, thanks for your comment. Before I made this post, I did tried 'pagecontainershow' but it doesn't trigger. The console log show no message at all.

Comment: Because  pagecontainer events can't be delegated to a specific page. They are emitted on page container.